# Subclass component to override event handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a complex React component (Combobox from react-widgets), and would like to change a small part of it's behavior - I want to override the onKeyDown event. If enter is pressed, I want to handle it myself, and the Combobox shouldn't see the keypress. Apart from that, I'd like it to be a drop-in replacement.

I know React strongly recommends composition over inheritance, but in this case composing seems bad - if I make a new component that includes Combobox, I'd have to forward every prop to the combobox:

```js
class MyCombobox extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<Combobox data={this.props.data}
                          value={this.props.value}
                          onChanged={this.props.onChanged}
                          ...
                />);
    }
}
```

I also tried just including a regular Combobox, and setting onKeyDown in its container, but that didn't override the event - the original Combobox still gets the event, and my Container gets it, too:

```js
// in MyContainer.render:
return (
    <div className="MyContainer">
        <Combobox data={...} onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} />
    </div>
);
```

This here *almost* works:

```js
class MyCombobox extends Combobox {
  handleKeyDown(event) {
    console.log('MyCombobox.handleKeyDown', event);
    console.log(this);  // this: null!

    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      event.preventDefault();
      // super.close();  // fails
    }
  }

  render() {
    let result = super.render();
    return React.cloneElement(result, {onKeyDown: this.handleKeyDown});
  }
}
```

I can intercept the event and prevent the Combobox from processing it. However, `this` is `null`. If I make `handleKeyPress` an arrow function instead, I can access `this` (it is the `MyCombobox` object), but I can't access any of the `Combobox`'s properties. Especially `super.close()` doesn't work (I get "'super' outside of function or class").

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it helps, but you can easily pass all the props to other component this way (using ES6 unwrapping):

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <SomeOtherComponent {...this.props} />
        )
    }
}
```

I think it might help you to solve your problem using composition.

Comment: Thanks, I just found that, too. Really neat, now I can use composition... but still, when I try to hook the event using `onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}`, both my component and the original combobox get the event.

Comment: Could you update your question showing how you perform composition of that?

Comment: Well, I tried exactly as you wrote, but that doesn't work. There seems to be no way of installing a handler before the child compontent's handler...

Answer (score 0):

So, this kind of works, and it seems to be doing things The React Way (composition, only passing information to children via props).

What it does is, when I enter custom text and press enter, it takes that text and closes the menu, instead of discarding the text and selecting some element of the list.

It still doesn't behave 100% like a native combo box, so I'm giving up for now and trying a different component :-). But maybe this is a useful workaround for someone else trying to "subclass" a component.

You might be able to simplify this, I'm not sure the manual handling of `value` is neccessary.

```
class MyCombobox extends Component {
  handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.setState({open: false, value: event.target.value});
    }
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {open: false, value: null};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Combobox value={this.state.value} open={this.state.open}
      onToggle={(isOpen)=>this.setState({open:isOpen})}
      onChange={(newValue)=>this.setState({value:newValue})}
      onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown} {...this.props} />
    );
  }
}
```